# Java web browser slow

Tags: java, browser, swt

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser
```

I load the embedded browser into Java and have it load a page.

It seems to load really slow... is this an issue with the page caching?  What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: Can you cite the problem page and post an sscce: http://pscode.org/sscce.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embedded browser is the Internet Explorer on Windows, and Mozilla on Linux. We use it too, but it works perfectly and is not slow at all. If you want to let it appear faster, you should load the page and make the browser visible afterwards.