# SWT Browser component blocks SWT UI thread

Tags: browser, swt, block, vaadin

I am embedding an org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser into a view in a modified eclipse (Indigo), for use as a preview pane of a form editor component. On a form model change or an element selection change the code renders the form via vaadin 6 and displays it in the browser component.

Now, this works like a charm in most cases. But for some highly complex forms the HTML+JS generated by vaadin generates a lot of stress on the browser, rendering it unresponsive for up to a few seconds. That in itself wouldn't be tragic (1), but as long as the SWT Browser component is busy rendering that stuff, the entire eclipse UI thread is blocked.

A simple way to reproduce this is to create an HTML page that blocks inside a javascript function (see https://gist.github.com/creinig/5150747 for an example) and display it in the SWT browser. As long as that JS function is running, the entire SWT application is not responding to anything.

The only info I've found on this problem are

- one [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657201/java-web-browser-slow) (without resolution) and
- one [question on EclipseZone](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t75738.html) (unanswered).

Not that helpful :(

The [API docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html) of the Browser component don't seem to offer any insight on whether its rendering is triggered periodically by the UI thread or if itself triggers something that blocks the UI.

Is there a way to decouple the Browser component's rendering from the SWT UI thread? Or anything else that could be done to protect the eclipse UI from hanging stuff in the browser?

---

(1): We need forms of this complexity level, we're already optimizing the rendering performance and a switch to vaadin7 will most likely also speed things up. But the problem will certainly persist, if only in reduced severity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real solution, but a workaround that Works For Me (TM):
As described [here](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2005/10/24/launching-an-external-browser-url-from-swt.html) it is really easy to launch the system's default browser from SWT. So I'm going to add an option to the view containing the browser control that will "detach" the view by disabling the browser control and opening the system browser instead.

In case the linked page drops off the net, here's the gist:

```
org.eclipse.swt.program.Program.launch("http://my.funny.url/");
```

launches the application registered for HTTP URLs. In other words: the system default browser.
Happiness ensues :)